# .Net Core Re-Write Strict Url

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, .net-core

I've project on .net core 2.1 where I rewrite urls like

```
var rewrites = new RewriteOptions()
                    .AddRewrite(@"GetCountryInfo", "Home/GetCountryInfo", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"about-us", "Home/About", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"pricing", "Home/Pricing", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"sign-in", "Home/Sign_in", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"sign-up", "Home/Sign_up", skipRemainingRules: true)
```

It's working fine but when something add with this url then also its working which are not acceptable.

Like

```
localhost:5000/about-us/abc
localhost:5000/about-us1
```

I want to ignore this /abc or 1 from url. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had solved this by two ways. Now I will describe in details.

1. Implementing UrlRules:

I wrote a class which inherits from IRule such as

```
public class UrlRules : IRule
    {
        public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            if (!IsValidUrl(request.Path))
            {
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
                context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = "/home/error";

            }
        }
        public bool IsValidUrl(string path)
        {
            bool urlValid = false;
            switch (path)
            {
                case "/":
                case "/about-us":
                case "/about-us/":
                case "/GetCountryInfo":
                case "/pricing":
                case "/pricing/":
                case "/sign-in":
                case "/sign-in/":
                case "/sign-up":
                case "/sign-up/":
                    urlValid = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    urlValid = false;
                    break;
            }
            return urlValid;
        }
    }
```

Then configure route like as

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                var rewrites = new RewriteOptions()
                    .Add(new UrlRules())
                    .AddRewrite(@"GetCountryInfo", "Home/GetCountryInfo", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"about-us", "Home/about", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"pricing", "Home/Pricing", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"sign-in", "Home/Sign_in", skipRemainingRules: true)
                    .AddRewrite(@"sign-up", "Home/Sign_up", skipRemainingRules: true);


                app.UseRewriter(rewrites);
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name:"default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

It's working.

2. Defining Route:

It's the perfect way to me. Just defining route into each action like as

```
[Route("~/about-us")]
        public IActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

It's the perfect solution to me causes it's working fine.